# Avoid nested calls

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

Let's say I have an aspect wrapper on all public methods of my services which detaches entities from database before returning them to controller:

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
```

When one service is calling another directly, this wrapper is being triggered as well. For instance:

```
@Service
class ServiceA {
    @Autowired
    ServiceB b;

    public void foo() {
        b.bar();
    }
}

@Service
class ServiceB {
    public void bar() {
    }
}
```

When I call `ServiceA.foo()`, the wrapper is triggering around the nested call to `bar()` as well.

It should trigger around the call to `foo()`, but not `bar()`. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sometimes resolved this kind of problems using [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variables. Try something like:

```
@Aspect
public class DetacherAspect {

    private final ThreadLocal<Object> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Object>();

    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
    public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        boolean isNested = threadLocal.get() != null;
        if (!isNested) {
            // Set some object (better create your own class) if this is the first service
            threadLocal.set(new Object());
        }

        try {


            ... // Your aspect


        } finally {

            // Clean thread local variables
            if (!isNested) {
                threadLocal.remove();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Obviously, this will only work when all calls are done in the same thread. Thread local variables have some other drawbacks too and is good to read about them.

Comment: I came up with this one as well, got me wondering if there really is no simpler way. Feels so common and natural.

Comment: @KonradGarus: Well, I've used this when I needed to share some object between calls. But I think it fits with your problem and is no so complicated (but I'm not a fan of using thread local variables like crazy).

Comment: I understand. I definitely fits, I'm just wondering if there is no solution out-of-the-box. Thanks, I'll accept this if there are no such answers.

Comment: @KonradGarus: Well, I'm curious about other solutions, too :)

Answer (score 0):

I am on the road with my iPad only, so I cannot test it now, but you could try something along the lines of:

```java
pointcut myCalls() :
    execution(public * *(..)) && @within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service);
pointcut myCallsNonRecursive() :
    myCalls() && !cflowbelow(myCalls())

around() : myCallsNonRecursive() {
    // ...
}
```

Sorry for the AspectJ native syntax, I am just more familiar with it.

Comment: From a glance at AspectJ docs it seems like it might work, but Spring docs quickly told me that it won't work with Spring.

Comment: I am not a Spring user. It there no way to weave with AJ and use the woven classes in Spring or even to delegate weaving in Spring to AJ?

Comment: Okay, I just stumpled upon this, I hope it helps: [Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj)